# Create loop to open multiple files and copy data to a master file in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, loops, copy

I have multiple files with data that need to be transposed into a single master file with all the data into a single row.

I'm a complete noob in programming so if the code I have so far doesn't make any sense, then please feel free to change it

I was able to find this "Loop all excel files in a folder" code from www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com   The code works perfectly fine, it will open up each file individually in the folder and then close it, and then open the next file and close it until it has gone through every file in that folder.

However, I'd like to insert a "copy and paste data" code loop within the loop.  So what needs to happen is, the code will open "File1" in the folder, and then copy and paste the data into the "Master File" in cell A4.  Then it will close "File1", and then open up "File2" and copy the data into "Master File" in cell A5 and then close "File2".  It will repeat this until all files in the folder have been opened/closed.

This is the code I have right now, but I can't get the copy and paste code to work properly.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set the loop up where the code will know what file it is currently on and setting a counter for the cell of the Master File that it is pasting into.

```
Sub LLoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and   perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "March"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancelhow
NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
 If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xlsx"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'THIS IS MY COPY AND PASTE CODE (DOESN'T WORK)
 Dim row As Integer
 While row = 4

 Workbooks("Filename:=myPath & myFile").Worksheets("Resin Log").cell("I5") = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
 Next row

'Save and Close Workbook
 wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Get next file name
  myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

 ResetSettings:
 'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to say if it would work if you don't provide any code...

Comment: also, if you search SO or even google, you are bound to find this exact code somewhere. this is a very common task - just suggesting to search a little more deeper

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the copy and paste code.  I've tried looking through google but none of them works in my case.  The code needs to open the current file it is on, copy the data from a specific cell, and paste it into the master file.  So for an example, opens "File1", copies cell "C1", and pastes it into "Master File" in cell "A4", then closes "File1".   Then it opens "File2", copies "C1", and pastes it into "Master File" in cell "A5" and closes "File2".  Then it'll open "File3", copies "C1", and pastes it into Master File in cell "A6", & closes "File3".  And so on...

Comment: Ok I figured it out.  I just added this code                                                  wb.Activate
Range("L1:M1").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Bldg 4 - Resin Log - Master - 1.xlsm").Activate
Range("A" & row).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: I updated my example for how to copy without using `.Copy` below, that said, if you want/need to, then at the least you shouldn't use `.Activate' or `.Select`. To avoid those A) Use `Workbooks("Fill_In_WB_Name").Worksheets("FIll_In_WS_Name")` to specify which workbook & worksheet; B) Instead of `Range("rng").Select` append `.Range("rng")` to the code from A to specify the cell(s) to use; C) Instead of `Selection.Copy` append `.copy` or `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. Select & Activate statements are NOT needed and really slow down your code. See my updated answer for other best practices.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what you're talking about. I would suggest, trying to just set cell values in the file being created directly

`targetworkbook.worksheets(1).Range("A1").value = sourceworkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C4").value`

rather than using `.Copy` & `.Paste` so that if the macro takes a while to run you aren't locked out of using Copy/Paste in other applications. If you're still unsure of what to do, try doing it with Record Macro turned on. The generated code will need tweaked, but will give you most of what you need.

Also, be sure to look at [this link](https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/) for some other things to avoid using in your code.

Comment: The problem is that I need the "copy and paste code" to copy the data from the current file that the loop is on.   So the loop opens up the first file, for example, "File1" and copies into the "Master File" into cell A4.  Then the loop closes "File 1", and opens up "File2", and copies the data into the "Master File" into cell A5.   And it'll go through File3 and onward, copying data into cell A6 and so on.   However, I'm a complete excel noob and tried many diff codes from google with no luck

Comment: No I got that was the intent. Refining my example, if MasterFile is the workbook variable `mf`, and `wb` is File1, you'd use `mf.worksheets(1).Range("A4").Value = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A4").value`. This has the same effect as copying the value, without actually having to perform a copy, which like I said prevents you from hitting Ctrl+C to copy in another application and screwing up your output.